# Flex Loading external swf prevents other functions

Tags: apache-flex, class, loader

I am able to use the Loader class to import an external swf into my project, its working great.
But Im also trying to do a ImageSnapshot of the stage which works fine before the external swf is imported.  After the swf is imported the ImageSnapshot no longer works.

Any idea?  is there a event that the external swf is bringing with it that would disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a `LoaderContext` object within the `Loader.load()` function. On that `LoaderContext`, set `checkPolicyFile` to true. Like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
loader.load(new URLRequest("your swf url"), loaderContext);
```

What the `checkPolicyFile` flag does is that it tells the host swf to load a policy file from the loaded swf's server. If you haven't specified that flag at loading time you will recieve a `SecurityError` when you try to get pixel data from the loaded swf through `BitmapData.draw()`.

Adobe docs on the subject: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#checkPolicyFile